# How to start OmniFind Text Search Server for DB2 for i

Tags: db2-400

I am trying to start an OmniFind server on DB2 / 400.

The "SELECT SERVERID, SERVERPORT, SERVERSTATUS, SERVERPATH FROM QSYS2.SYSTEXTSERVERS;" request returns the id of the server I want to start (see image)

Is the SQL startup command of the server correct?

CALL SYSPROC.SYSTS_START (50);

Comment: what happens when you do that?

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to? the IBM documentation [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/rzash/omniz_startingomniserver.htm) says:

> OMNIFIND starts the text search server automatically as needed, as long as the SERVERSTATUS in QSYS2.SYSTEXTSERVERS is 0.

Comment: No, you’re wrong : you have to run a stored procedure to launch the server. I see that with a the ibm support.

Comment: This is not personal opinion, it is a direct copy from the documentation. They do also mention a way to manually start the server if necessary. That is if the server doesn't start when the host starts. Are you sure you have it installed?

Comment: Ok, many thanks for your help. Our problem is because of we have many ptf’s to install for this product. I’ m working with system engineer to resolve this anomaly.  Many thanks for your advice.